# How to write a shellscript for mongoexport command?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use "mongoexport" command in shellscript. So, that we can export a particular collection into a json file.

Can anyone please help me out regarding the usage of "mongoexport" command in shellscipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script (if the path would be correct) prints out the mongoexport version.

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/mongoexport --version
```

You can use any other commands you normally use in the command line in the script. you can find those here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Comment: Can you please edit a sample shellscript file for "mongoexport" command

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. This should be all the information you need. You will need to read a bit to make it work with your setup..

Comment: Actually, I'm able to export a json file using mongoexport shell command. But, I'm trying to export a json file using shellscript. I'm new to shellscript. So, asking you, how to use a mongoexport command in shellscript.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to path where your MongoDB is installed.
Provide export command.

```
CD /D C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin
mongoexport -d <DBNAME> -c <COLLECTION-NAME> -o <FILENAME>
```